# Spring RestTemplate gives 500 error but Postman works?

Tags: java, spring, api

I am trying to do a GET request with the code I have below

```
String baseUrl = "https://americas.api.riotgames.com/lol/match/v5/matches/";

String query = "NA1_4140996656";

String encodedQuery = encodeValue(query); // Encoding a query string

String url = baseUrl + encodedQuery;


HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("X-Riot-Token","XXXXXXXXX");
headers.add("Origin","https://developer.riotgames.com");
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
System.out.println(url);
HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = new RestTemplate().exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
System.out.println("did it hit?");
//JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response.getBody());

String json = response.getBody();
return json;
```

When I do the get request on postman using the same exact url and headers it works. Other requests I made using the same format above works as well. I don't know why when I make this specific request it gives me a `500 error`.

Any Advice would be appreciated

Comment: You can get more information from server end as the error code is 500.

Comment: @harry i am calling an external api, it works on postman perfectly fine but in the code I am getting a 500. I dont think it has any errors on the server side.

Comment: Could you share the postman request details from the console?

Comment: @harry sure here it is https://imgur.com/a/GMyy4Pv

Comment: What is inside `encodeValue` method?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I was using it to encode the url but even if I dont use it and place the url directly it wont work. I dont even have to encode it for this particular one.